# Select rows in a pandas data frame based on multiple column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as below

```
id     date  time  domain       activity
1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
2  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
2  21stdec     6  amazon  add to basket
```

How do I get rid of rows which contain the same value in the activity column (i.e for `device_id = 2` the only activity is `add to basket`. I still want to preserve the format for `id 1` which has multiple(duplicate) values of `add to basket` but it has other activity as well

I tried `pd.drop_duplicates` however that doesn't solves the problem.

Edit : None of the below solutions works , I Need the output as below

```
id     date  time  domain       activity
1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
```

The data for id = 2 should be deleted like all the activity irrespective of date/time contains nothing but add to basket, so all the single activity rows should be deleted and only keep rows of data that have multiple activity listed i.e as in id =1 has 2 levels of activity ( Product view and Add to basket)

Apologies if it caused any misinterpretation

Thanks

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['date','time','domain','activity'])` don't work?

Comment: Dear OP please accept [`jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226198/8320861) answer as he provided the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, Use `groupby` + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and calculate [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) for values not equal to ([`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html)) `1` and then use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `subset` parameter:

```
df.dropna(how='all',inplace=True)
cols = df.columns
df['Unique'] = df.groupby('id')['activity'].transform('nunique')
mask = df['Unique'].ne(1)
df.loc[mask,'Unique'] = df.loc[mask,'Unique'].cumsum()

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['activity','Unique'])[cols]

print(df1)

   id     date  time  domain       activity
0   1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1   1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
2   1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
3   1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
5   2  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
```

---

**Explanation :**

```
print(df.groupby('id')['activity'].transform('nunique'))
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
5    1
6    1
Name: activity, dtype: int64

print(df['Unique'].ne(1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Unique, dtype: bool

# After the line df.loc[mask,'Unique'] = df.loc[mask,'Unique'].cumsum()
print(df['Unique'])
0    2
1    4
2    6
3    8
5    1
6    1
Name: Unique, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) with filtering by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) `ne(1)` what return not unique groups:

```
print (df)
   id     date  time  domain       activity
0   1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1   1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
2   1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
3   1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
4   2  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
5   2  21stdec     6  amazon  add to basket
6   3  21stdec     6  amazon  add to basket

df = df[df.groupby('id')['activity'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
print (df)

   id     date  time  domain       activity
0   1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1   1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
2   1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
3   1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
```

Another solutions for remove only duplicated groups per columns `id` and `activity`, so unique rows are not removed:

```
idx = df.loc[~df.duplicated(['id','activity'], keep=False), 'id'].unique()
df = df[df['id'].isin(idx)]
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df.duplicated(['id','activity'], keep=False).groupby(df['id']).transform('all')]

print (df)
   id     date  time  domain       activity
0   1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1   1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
2   1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
3   1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
6   3  21stdec     6  amazon  add to basket
```

Comment: I might be overthinking to this problem :). But still, the question is not clear.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I have edited the question to be more clear, No longer a guessing game :-)

Comment: @NehaSharma `df[df.groupby('id')['activity'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]` this is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `subset` parameter in `drop_duplicates`:

```
dataset.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'activity'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to only drop duplicates, where `id == 2`. You can still use `drop_duplicates`, but you have to specify `subset='activity'` in only that rows of the dataframe which have `id==2`. Then you `concat` it together with that rows having `id==1`

```
df = pd.concat([df[df['id'] == 1], df[df['id'] == 2].drop_duplicates(subset='activity')])
```

gives

```
   id     date  time  domain       activity
0   1  20thdec     2  amazon  add to basket
1   1  21stdec     2  amazon   product view
2   1  21stdec     3  amazon  add to basket
3   1  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
4   2  21stdec     4  amazon  add to basket
```